# Как добавить VR фото на сайт

Tags: javascript, three.js, vr, virtualtour

Здравствуйте, мне необходимо добавить на сайт фото 360 (виртуальная реальность), отснятые при помощи Samsung Gear 360. Как это реализовать?

Опыта в этом деле нету, я находил информацию о том что можно воспользоваться Three.js или Babylon, но не смог разобраться. Можно как на отдельной странице так и в модальном окне и т.п.

Comment: А где вопрос ,или нам к шаманам обращаться ?

Comment: Вопрос собственно в том как добавить 360 фото на сайт.

Comment: фото кубическое?

Comment: Фото сферические.

Comment: [Панорамы](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=panorama) в Three.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если без гугл-карт или Яндекс-карт, как вариант three js или вот это:
https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/sky/

Вот как по ссылке в примере выглядит код html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Panorama</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Panorama — A-Frame">
    <script src="../../../dist/aframe-master.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-sky src="puydesancy.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Где puydesancy.jpg - сферическая картинка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Действительно работает, но появилась другая проблема, фото которые я использую отсняты на Samsung gear 360, там фото выглядит как 2 сферы (Dual fisheye кажется) при их сшивании ужасные шви образовываются как с этим справится?

Comment: Тут я вам, к сожалению, не помогу, юзал только готовые изображения и сгенерированные гугкартами из ведроид-приложения. Во втором случае швы тоже были видны, люди пишут, что фоткать надо аккуратно. Возможно, нужно порыться в настройках камеры, поэкспериментируйте.